# Loading saved Keras model fails: ValueError: Inconsistent values for attr 'Tidx' DT_FLOAT vs. DT_INT32 while building NodeDef

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The code below generates the **error**:

```
ValueError: Inconsistent values for attr 'Tidx' DT_FLOAT vs. DT_INT32 while building NodeDef
```

tf_op_layer_Mean_17/Mean_17' using Op<name=Mean; signature=input:T, reduction_indices:Tidx -> output:T; attr=keep_dims:bool,default=false; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_UINT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]; attr=Tidx:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]>

**Code**:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
#tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

inputs = Input(shape=(2,))
output_loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(inputs)
outputs = [inputs, output_loss]
model = Model(inputs, outputs)

loss = tf.reduce_mean((output_loss)) #Error
#loss = tf.math.rsqrt((output_loss)) #No Error
model.add_loss(loss)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=[None] * len(model.outputs))
model.fit(np.random.random((5, 2)), epochs=2)

model.save("my_model_.h5")

#Error when loading and loss tf.reduce_mean
model_ = keras.models.load_model("my_model_.h5", compile=False)# ValueError: Inconsistent values for attr 'Tidx' DT_FLOAT vs. DT_INT32 while building NodeDef 'tf_op_layer_Mean_1/Mean_1'
model_.summary()
```

Note that the loss function causes the error. A change in the loss function (uncomment the sqrt loss) results in no error. Any suggestions would be great! This is also related to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47309).

Update, I tried closure for the loss function, it did not work.

```
class Custom_Reduce_Mean_Loss(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
    def __call__(self, input):        
        return tf.cast(tf.reduce_mean(input), dtype=tf.float32)
    def get_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)

loss = Custom_Reduce_Mean_Loss()(output_loss)
```

Comment: I tried casting ```loss = tf.cast(tf.reduce_mean((output_loss)), dtype=tf.float32)```.  Same error.

Answer (score 0):

The model saves and loads if `loss = tf.reduce_mean((output_loss))`is applied via a lambda function (is replaced by) `loss = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x))(output_loss)`